# ListServ not accepting email posting

Tags: email

So I'm having trouble with technology that's 25 years old and has no substantial tech support, so this post is really just a last-resort shot in the dark in case someone has some enlightenment.

I'm a member of a ListServ mailing list. I'm receiving emails from the list just fine, but I can't appear to send any emails to the list. The worst part is... I never get any error messages. The emails that I try to send just never show up. The site has an online form for posting to the list, and if I use that form, it says "Your message has been successfully posted to the (LISTNAME) list.", but still, the message never actually shows up.

I don't suppose anyone has any idea what could be causing this?

(In case it matters, the list is being hosted at http://oracle.wizards.com/archives/index.html, though it's not a public list, so it doesn't actually show up on that page, and I can't disclose what it is. They appear to be running ListServ 14.4).